# Failed when creating a skeleton WiX extension

Tags: c#, dll, wix

I just started using WiX, with zero knowledge of C#/.NET

Now I'm trying to create a simple WiX extension by referring this page: [WiX3 - Simple Example of Extension](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/extension_development_simple_example.htm).

Here is steps described in that page:

- In Visual Studio, create a new C# library (.dll) project named SampleWixExtension.
- Add a reference to wix.dll to your project.
- Add a using statement that refers to the Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml namespace.

  `using Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml;`
- Make your SampleWixExtension class inherit from WixExtension.

  `public class SampleWixExtension : WixExtension {}`
- Add the AssemblyDefaultWixExtensionAttribute to your AssemblyInfo.cs.

  `[assembly: AssemblyDefaultWixExtension(typeof(SampleWixExtension.SampleWixExtension))]`
- Build the project.

However, when I finished these steps and built this project, I met following errors:

```
    ------ Build started: Project: SampleWixExtension, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
    D:\working\test\SampleWixExtension\SampleWixExtension\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(37,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AssemblyDefaultWixExtension' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    D:\working\test\SampleWixExtension\SampleWixExtension\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs(37,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AssemblyDefaultWixExtensionAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

    Compile complete -- 2 errors, 0 warnings
```

Anyone know why and how to fix it?

Btw, in the Solution Explorer I can see `wix` is already in References, its properties has Path of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Installer XML v3.5\bin\wix.dll`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By adding

```
using Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml;
```

into AssemblyInfo.cs, the project is now successfuly built.